# Dynamic memory in a struct

Tags: struct, malloc

So, my struct is like this:

```
struct player{
 char name[20];
 int time;
}s[50];
```

I don't know how many players i am going to add to the struct, and i also have to use dynamic memory for this. So how can i allocate and reallocate more space when i add a player to my struct?
I am inexperienced programmer, but i have been googling for this for a long time and i also don't perfectly understand structs.
This site doesn't accept my question so let's put some more text to this post

Comment: One solution to get a "variable" number of "items" is to implement a [linked list](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf).

Comment: That could have been best way to go, but i am almost finished with this program, and the only thing i need is to combine mallocing with this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are programming in C/C++.
Your struct player has static-allocated fields, so, when you use malloc on it, you are asking space for a 20-byte char array a for one integer.

My suggestion is to store in a variable (or #define a symbol) the initial number of structures you can accept. Then, use malloc to allocate a static array that contains these structures. 
Also you have to think about a strategy to store new players coming. The simplest one could be have an index variable to store last free position and use it to add over that position.

A short example follows:

```
#define init_cap 50

struct player {
    char name[20];
    int time;
};

int main() {
    int index;

    struct player* players;
    players = (struct player*) malloc(init_cap * sizeof(struct player));

    for(i = 0; i < init_cap; i++) {
        strcpy(players[i].name, "peppe");
        players[i].time = i;
    }

    free(players);

    return 0;
}
```

At this point you should also think about reallocating memory if the number of players you get a runtime exceeds your initial capacity. You can use:

```
players = (struct player*) realloc(2 * init_cap * sizeof(struct player));
```

in order to double the initial capacity.

At the end, always remember to free the requested memory.